# After replacing incandescent bulbs with LED bulbs, why am I getting flickering from some of them, but not all, on dimmer switches

Tags: led, dimmer-switch

I've replaced a bunch of light bulbs with LED bulbs (specifically, these: https://www.homedepot.com/p/EcoSmart-75-Watt-Equivalent-BR20-Dimmable-Energy-Star-LED-Light-Bulb-Bright-White-3-Pack-1003020602/303701036) and am now experiencing occasional flickering on some of the dimmer switches. All the wiring in the house was re-done in 2013 during a gut renovation, and I am using the same model dimmable ecosmart LED bulb throughout. Also this is in the US. I've made sure the bulbs are screwed into the socket quite firmly, so I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: What make and model are the dimmers?

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR Your Dimmers are Not Compatible with the Bulbs

Older dimmers don't work with most LED lights. Period. Many newer dimmers work together with newer "Dimmer Compatible" bulbs (as yours are listed). There are even some dimmers available today that are not LED-compatible, and 2013 or older dimmers are very likely to be not LED-compatible.

That being said, there are times when *some* combinations of LED-compatible Dimmer and Dimmer-compatible LED aren't quite compatible enough. But my hunch is that a new, good quality, LED-compatible dimmer will solve the problem.

Feel free to post the model # of one of the existing dimmers, as that may confirm the problem.

Comment: Yes agreed. I had this same problem. A new dimmer I bought on Amazon did not work with some new LED bulbs, but was fine with others. Switching the dimmer for a locally purchased one (at a somewhat higher price) solved it. To the OP: a bit of experimentation with combinations will likely solve it.

Comment: OTOH, I discovered that my old skewl rotary dimmer that I'd been using for my ceiling fan lights worked perfectly well with the new ceiling fan and dimmable LED bulbs that were supplied with it (no recollection what brand/model the bulbs were). I updated to an LED compatible dimmer since this was the 3rd of 6 fans being replaced and the others had been updated, as well, but I was surprised that it worked just fine with no apparent flickering at all. For a short time, at least. (This answer does have my +1)